# Make function call wait for web SQL query

Tags: javascript, callback, web-sql

Primecheck function is supposed to return true or false whether passed number is prime or not. If the number is prime, function adds it to PRIMES table.
This is a Sieve of Eratosthenes algorithm, but it's not finished yet.

```
function primecheck (number) {
    var isprime = true;
        if (number%10 == 1 || number%10 == 3 || number%10 == 7 || number%10 == 9) {
        db.transaction(function (tx) {
            tx.executeSql('SELECT * from Primes', [], function (tx, result) {
                for (var i = 1; i < result.rows.length; i++) {
                    if (number%result.rows.item(i)['prime'] == 0) {
                        isprime = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (isprime) {
                    tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO PRIMES (prime) values (?)', [number]);
                }
                return isprime;
            }, null);
        }, null, null);

    }
    else {
        isprime = false;
        return isprime;
    }
}
```

**Problem:** when I pass numbers that do not end on 1, 3, 7, 9, function returns true, it's ok.
But when I pass other numbers, function returns undefined. I suppose it's because function call doesn't "wait" for SQL query to finish, so I must use some kind of callback functions. But it didn't work.

Comment: Pass the callback as the second argument of `primecheck`, and execute `callback(isprime)` instead of `return isprime`. (Also, you don't need to select primes which are larger than `sqrt(number)`).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your function performs asynchronous operations, it cannot return a value based on the result of those asynchronous operations. (This is because the asynchronous functions won't run until the current execution is finished, due to the single-threaded nature of JavaScript.) Instead, your function should expect a callback function that takes the would-be return value as an argument.

You currently call your function like:

```
var isprime = primecheck(someNum);
// now do something with isprime
```

But you need to use a callback:

```
primecheck(someNum, function(isprime) {
    // now do something with isprime
});
```

Just add a second callback argument, and call that callback instead of using a `return`:

```
function primecheck (number, callback) {
    var isprime = true;
        if (number%10 == 1 || number%10 == 3 || number%10 == 7 || number%10 == 9) {
        db.transaction(function (tx) {
            tx.executeSql('SELECT * from Primes', [], function (tx, result) {
                //....
                callback(isprime);
            }, null);
        }, null, null);
    }
    else {
        isprime = false;
        callback(isprime);
    }
}
```

Now, `primecheck` returns nothing, but the callback function you pass into `primecheck` will get fired with `isprime` as its first argument whenever `primecheck` determines the primality of the input.